# Ruby, perform operation on an array and return the new array, aswell as "changes"

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am looking for a way to perform a certain operation (for instance delete_if) on an array and return both the deleted elements, and the remaining elements.

For example

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
a.delete_if {|x| x.even? } #=> [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]]
```

But what I am looking for is something like

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
a.some_operation #=> [[1,3,5,7,9],[2,4,6,8,10]]
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @falsetru yes.. my bad, I made an edit

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Enumerable#partition`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
a.partition &:even?
# => [[2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]]
```

The first element of the `Enumerable#partition` return value contains the elements that are evaluated to true in the block. So you need to use [`odd?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-odd-3F) to get what you want.

```
a.partition &:odd?
# => [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
a.group_by { |x| x.even? }.values
#=> [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]
```